# Why is my object exporting into keyshot like this?

Tags: modeling, blender-internal-render-engine

The top image is how it imported in keyshot. 
The second image is my model in blender. 
I can add the blender file if that helps!

[image: this is my obj import]

[image: Here it is In blender]

[image]

Comment: You have too complex, concave faces. Try to replace them with "Bridge Edge Loops" or "Grid Fill"

Comment: We can make educated guesses, but perhaps it's better if you add the file. https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @rjg i added the .blend file. Didnt know how. Thank you.

Comment: @FFeller i tried doing that, but it closed off that space, and i want it to be open.

Comment: Your geometry contains several ngons and you have disconnected geometry. Try to create clean topology using only quads.